# Man washes up on a beach without memory

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for the name of a movie I vaguely remember watching around 1997.

The plot was about a man being washed up on a beach with memory loss. He's taken in by a woman  who is a psychology student/enthusiast and trying to analyze him and help him get his memory back.

**Edit**: 
I think the movie was taking place in the UK, but I'm not 100% sure about that. The movie wasn't based on real events, and he gets his memory back in the end. The sea theme is very prominent in the movie, and I think the last shot of the movie is an empty, stormy beach.

I think the name of the movie might have included 'sea' or 'memory' but so far I haven't found anything in that direction.

Comment: Interesting premise. Is there anything else you could add? Watched in a theater or on video? What country were you in when you watched it? A vague description of either of the main characters? Language they spoke and accent? No detail that you remember clearly is too small in this type of question.

Comment: I assumed it was a love story, but I can't find anything. What kind of movie is it? Romantic, drama, thriller?

Comment: Isn't there a famous unsolved case from maybe Australia about a guy that appeared on a beach with no idea who he is?  Could this movie be based on that?

Comment: Looks like the movie is The Majestic, but it was released in 2001
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Majestic_%28film%29

Comment: It's not The Majestic, seems there's no shortage in movies featuring memory loss

Comment: I'm not giving this as an answer because the man isn't washed up on a beach, but is it possible this is The Prince of Tides.

Comment: The "man found on a beach with no memory" trope is so popular that I can think of 2 more dramas with this exact plot that haven't been mentioned yet. (Won't put them up as answers, though, because I don't think the female character has anything to do with psychology in either of them.)

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like [Driftwood](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112904/) (1997)

> When Sarah walks alone along the desolate beach one day she find an
> unconscious man, who has been brought to land by the waves. When he
> awakens he doesn't remember anything. He has no name and no past. His
> dependence lies on Sarah.

Its also set in Northern Ireland which jibes with what you're remembering.

Comment: It's close, but I don't think that's the one. I'll try to get my hands on Driftwood to be certain.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120257/
Amy Foster (1997)
The film tells the story of Russian emigree and the only survivor from ship crash Yanko Goorall and servant Amy Foster in the end of 19th century.

IMDb Storyline:

> The film tells the story of Russian emigree and the only survivor from ship crash Yanko Goorall and servant Amy Foster in the end of 19th century. When Yanko enters a farm sick and hungry after the shipwreck, everyone is afraid of him, except for Amy, who is very kind and helps him. Soon he becomes like a son for Dr. James Kennedy and romance between Yanko and Amy follows.

Answer (score 1):

Could the movie you are looking for be called [Ladies in Lavender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladies_in_Lavender)?  Judi Dench and Maggie Smith star in this beautiful movie about two sisters who find a mysterious boy who washes up on the beach of their 1930's Cornish seaside village.

Answer (score 1):

Could be [I Know Who You Are](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0239955/?ref_=kw_li_tt) (Sé quién eres)

> Paloma is a young psychiatrist, who is hired to work as a director of a clinic in Galicia, and is attracted to Mario, her very first patient. He suffers from a rare form of amnesia, commonly known as Korsakov's syndrome. As a result, both his short and long term memories are affected, and he has temporary lapses of perception. However, Paloma finds Mario to be a fascinating individual, not just a regular patient. Intrigued, she decides to explore Mario's past and, through their dialogues, their relationship takes an unexpected turn.